# Increase my script perfomance and speed - Google apps script

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I have data in "Raw data" sheet 45000 rows. So I created a function that whenever I run this function will group my data to pivot table may be in 500 rows and turn to new format but totally take more than 30 minutes.

```
function sumData() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Raw data');
  var sourceData = spreadsheet.getRange('A1:I100000');
  var pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Pivot table'), true);
  sourceData = spreadsheet.getRange('\'Raw data\'!A1:I100000');
  pivotTable = spreadsheet.getRange('A1').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  var pivotValue = pivotTable.addPivotValue(3, SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.COUNTA);
  pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(6);
  pivotGroup.showTotals(false).showRepeatedLabels();
  pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(2);
  pivotGroup.showTotals(false).showRepeatedLabels();
  pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(3);
  pivotGroup.showTotals(false);

  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Pivot table');
  var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Summary data');
  ss2.getRange('A:D').activate();
  ss2.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});

  ss2.setFrozenRows(1);
  var value = [["Shop order", "Part number", "count Workstation", "Workstation"]];
  var range = ss2.getRange("A1:D1");
  range.setValues(value);

  var data = ss1.getRange(1, 1).getValue()
  for(var i = 1, j = 1; i < ss1.getLastRow()+1; i++) {
    var normalCase = true
    if(i!=1) {
      if(ss1.getRange(i, 1).getValue() == data) {
        normalCase = false
        ss2.getRange(j, 3).setValue(ss1.getRange(i, 4).getValue()+ss2.getRange(j, 3).getValue()) // for update count workstation
        ss2.getRange(j, 4).setValue(ss1.getRange(i, 3).getValue()+ " = " +ss1.getRange(i, 4).getValue()+ ", " +ss2.getRange(j, 4).getValue()) // for update value 
      } else {
        j++}}
    if(normalCase) {
      ss2.getRange(j, 1).setValue(ss1.getRange(i, 1).getValue())
      ss2.getRange(j, 2).setValue(ss1.getRange(i, 2).getValue())
      ss2.getRange(j, 3).setValue(ss1.getRange(i, 4).getValue())
      ss2.getRange(j, 4).setValue(ss1.getRange(i, 3).getValue()+ " = " +ss1.getRange(i, 4).getValue())}
    data = ss1.getRange(i, 1).getValue()}
  ss2.deleteRow(2);
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert('Summarize complete.');
};
```

**Is there any way to make my code run faster or maybe just a way to make the script run in 10-15 minutes?**

Comment: Is this information useful for your situation? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations

Comment: A single [`setValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) is faster than multiple `setValue`s

Comment: Please, provide us with a data sample so as we are able to reproduce your situation (ofc, please, replace any personal data with dummy info). In addition to the above, `getRange()` and `getValue` are also heavy methods and you should never put them inside loops (use a single `getValues()`, then operate on an in-memory `Array`, when done -> `setValues()` once)